# What indexes should one use for this two-table setup?

Tags: mysql, index, index-tuning, mysql-5.0

I have the following two-table setup:

```
CREATE TABLE relationships (
    id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    type varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY id_type (id,type)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE content_relations (
    relationship_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    site_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    content_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (relationship_id,site_id,content_id),
    KEY relationship (relationship_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

The currently used indexes are included, but that's exactly my question:

**Given the above tables and the following queries, what indexes should one use (instead)?**

---

For the **first** table only, the following queries are performed (each with the given frequency):

```
SELECT type
FROM relationships
WHERE id = X;
```

Frequency: **high**

---

```
DELETE
FROM relationships
WHERE id = X;
```

Frequency: **low**

---

---

For the **second** table only, the following queries are performed (each with the given frequency):

```
SELECT site_id, content_id
FROM content_relations
WHERE relationship_id = X;
```

Frequency: **high**

---

```
DELETE
FROM content_relations
WHERE relationship_id = X
    AND site_id = Y;
```

Frequency: moderate

---

```
DELETE
FROM content_relations
WHERE relationship_id = X;
```

Frequency: **low**

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT relationhip_id
FROM content_relations
WHERE site_id = X;
```

Frequency: **very low**

---

---

Lastly, there is the following query using **both** tables:

```
SELECT r.id
FROM relationships r
INNER JOIN content_relations cr ON r.id = cr.relationship_id
WHERE cr.site_id = X
    AND cr.content_id = Y
    AND r.type = Z
LIMIT 1;
```

Frequency: **very high**

---

---

The first table (i.e., `relationships`) has an auto-incremented (and thus unique) column `id`, so there is the `PRIMARY KEY (id)`. I guess that's okay. ;)
Both queries using this table only include just the primary key's column, so that's very good already.
Then there is the query using both tables, which also includes the `type` column. Does it make sense to use the unique composite `KEY (id,type)` here? Or is it redundant, or at least not of great advantage? Please keep in mind that there are just a few different values for the `type` column.

The second table (i.e., `content_relations`) currently has a `PRIMARY KEY` that consists of the (unique) combination of all three columns. This key is used for the last query using both tables, and also serves as constraint, because for every relationship(_id) and site(_id) there can only be one (or no) content element with a specific ID.
There are two queries using just the `relationship_id` column in the `WHERE` clause, that's why there is the `KEY (relationship_id)`.
Then there is one query that also includes the `site_id` column. Should one therefore add the composite `KEY (relationship_id,site_id)`?
I suppose there is no need for the `KEY (site_id)`, which would only be used by a single, very infrequent query, right?

Note: The `KEY (relationship_id)` is basically a foreign key to the `relationships` table. However, as I am working in an environment that allows for MySQL versions/engines that do not include foreign key constraints, I cannot use a real `FOREIGN KEY`, and all its benefits. But this shouldn't be relevant for my question(s), right?

---

**// EDIT:**  Here is a little more context.
I didn't put it in the question before just because it was already pretty bulky. Since an answerer asked for more, I will do this now, though. Be prepared, however, it's quite a lot information.

The tables are about relationships between content elements (CE). Each CE has an ID and a type. For each type, there is only one CE with a specific ID. There may, however, be CEs `A` and `B` (with types `A` and `B`), and both have the same ID.

Relations are allowed between two or more CEs that A) have the same type, and B) are from different sites (represented by their unique ID). That's why the `type` column is part of the `relationships` table (rather than being a column in the `content_relations` table).

Sites are stored in another table, which I cannot alter in any way. I just use the sites' unique IDs, and that's all.

The CEs are stored in type-specific tables, which I also cannot alter in any way. I just use a CE's ID **and** its type, and thus have a unique identifier.

The `AUTO_INCREMENT` for the `id` column in the `relationships` table is used, because there are lots of relationships for a specific type, and I need a unique identifier for every relationship. When inserting a new relationship for a given type, I just have to provide the `type`, and automatically get a unique `id`. That's what `AUTO_INCREMENT` is for, isn't it? Or did I misunderstand you, @Rick James?

I guess I don't really need `bigint`. As I reference other tables' columns, however, and as these columns are defined as `bigint(20)`, I thought it okay, if not wise, to use the same definition.

There are two usages of `LIMIT 1`. For the first one, there shouldn't even be more than one entry (because I query for `id` and compare `type`, and `(id,type)` is unique). So yes, I could/should remove this, thanks. The second time, however, there might be several entries - all with the same `relationship_id`. That's why I happily stop if I got one result.

Is there anything else I should provide you with?

---

Here is a **visual representation** of what this is all about:

[image: visual representation]

The individual figures represent individual **content elements**, while their individual **type** is represented by their individual shape, and their **ID** is written inside. Each color represents a **relationship** (i.e., a group of related content elements). As you can see, for any color (i.e., **relationship**), the shape (i.e., **type**) is the same, while there is not more than one figure (i.e., **content element**) from each **site**.

I hope this makes it more clear - and not more confusing.

Comment: If the _pair_ (id, type) is unique, then that should be the `PRIMARY KEY` and it is wrong to have PK(id), which says an id cannot have two types.

Comment: If you change `BIGINT` to `INT UNSIGNED`, you must do it in all tables, else the `JOINs`, `FOREIGN KEYS`, etc, may be very inefficient.

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT` is a handy way to have a `PRIMARY KEY` (which is _required_ for InnoDB).  But don't add it if you have a "good enough" "natural" PK.

Comment: `LIMIT 1` -- If you are happy to get _any_ one, then fine.

Comment: `relationships` still does not feel "right".

Comment: @RickJames The _pair_ `(id,type)` is unique, yes, because `id` alone is unique. I could use `(id,type)` as PK, yes, but you got that wrong. Any given ID cannot have more than one type. There may, however, be several entries with the same type - and each has a different ID.

Comment: @RickJames I absolutely understand/share your feeling about `relationships`. I guess, however, that stems from the fact that I use _external_ tables (for the CEs and the sites), and thus cannot properly _normalize_ my tables...? I couldn't come up with a better set of tables.

Comment: (id, type) -- OK; I misinterpreted you earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Specific comments**

```
PRIMARY KEY (id),
UNIQUE KEY id_type (id,type)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

The `UNIQUE` key is totally useless.  InnoDB "clusters" the data with the PRIMARY KEY.  That is looking up `id` lets you immediately find the rest of the columns, including `type`.  Also, a PK *is* a UNIQUE key, so the unique key adds no useful constraint.

```
WHERE id = X
```

The PK takes care of that.  (Both `SELECT` and `DELETE`)

```
PRIMARY KEY (relationship_id,site_id,content_id),
KEY relationship (relationship_id)
```

Similarly, the KEY is useless, DROP it.

The table seems a bit strange.  Is it describing relationships between sites and contents?  And there can be multiple relationships between each pair?

The PK for that table is fine for most queries. But...

```
SELECT DISTINCT relationhip_id
FROM content_relations
WHERE site_id = X;
```

will do a "table scan".  Since you say it has "very low" frequency, that may be OK.  But if you decide to speed it up, add

`INDEX(site_id, relationship_id)`

```
INNER JOIN content_relations cr ON r.id = cr.relationship_id
WHERE cr.site_id = X
  AND cr.content_id = Y
  AND r.type = Z
```

If the optimizer starts with `cr`,

```
cr: INDEX(site_id, content_id) -- in either order
r:  the existing PK will be used
```

would be optimal.

If it starts with `r`:

```
r:  INDEX(type, id) -- in this order  (fixed)
cr: the existing PK will be used
```

**Side notes:**

- I see no reason for adding `id AUTO_INCREMENT` to the relations table
- Do you really need `BIGINT` (8 bytes), almost no one exceeds `INT UNSIGNED` (4 bytes, max of 4 billion) for ids.
- Why `LIMIT 1`?  You don't care which one?  (Perhaps you want an `ORDER BY`?  Caution: That would add wrinkles to the optimal indexes!)
- Is `relationships` just a mapping from an id to a number?  Don't bother.  Get rid of the table, and simply use `type` in other tables.
- [More on creating optimal indexes](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

**Structure of InnoDB Indexes**

A table is a BTree, ordered by the `PRIMARY KEY`.  A leaf node contains all the columns of the table.

A secondary index (`UNIQUE` or not) is a BTree, ordered by the secondary key.  A leaf node contains the columns of the `PRIMARY KEY`.  This implies that, when you look up a row via a secondary key, it first drills down the secondary BTree, then drills down the Primary BTree.

A "covering index" contains all the columns needed for the `SELECT`, hence there is no need to "reach over" into the data.

`UNIQUE` is a regular index (secondary index arranged in a BTree), plus a uniqueness constraint.  When `INSERTing`, the constraint is checked.  (There are other minor aspects of `UNIQUE`.)

Back to your question about needing (or not) `UNIQUE(id,type)`:  `PRIMARY KEY(id)` says there is a BTree ordered by the *unique* column `id`.  Adding `UNIQUE (id, type)` would build another BTree, containing only `id` and `type` (the secondary columns) and nothing extra to handle the PK.  Performing `SELECT type FROM .. WHERE id=123` will drill down a BTree to find `123` and find `type` right there.  This statement applies whether it uses the PK or the secondary key.  Hence, I say that the secondary key cannot justify its existence.

As for "INDEX(site_id,content_id) although relationship_id ...", note that I said that the secondary key will have the columns of the PK.  So, it is effectively `INDEX(site_id, content_id, relationship_id)`  Explicitly listing all 3 columns has the advantage of making it more obvious that you have a "covering" index.  Note:  The *order* of the columns in a composite index *does* matter.

Comment: I will file an edit to the question and add more details on its context, and respond to your side notes, as well. I will notify you via comment once I'm done. Regarding the _clustering_ with the PK: do you mean I don't have to specify the index `(id,type)` to be `UNIQUE`, or that I don't need that index at all? Then, why only `INDEX(site_id,content_id)` although `relationship_id` is also part of the query (as part of the `JOIN` condition)? Table `r` has no `relationship_id`, but `id`, so you mean that? Table `r` has no `relationship_id`, but `id`, so you mean `INDEX(type,id)`, right?

Comment: I added to my dissertation.

Comment: I will have a look at your edit. I also finished my edit to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your index `KEY relationship (relationship_id)` is obsolete. It's a duplicate index as the PK `PRIMARY KEY (relationship_id,site_id,content_id)` starts by sorting `relationship_id` so the queries on this field will use the PK.

Note that I always create a ID field of type INT (or BIGINT for big tables, storing logs for instance) for the PK, then you can add a UNIQUE KEY of the field(s) you want but the PK should be simple as possible. It facilitates consistency checks and deployment on cluster solution as Galera.

Second note, you should always set the `UNSIGNED` option on your PK field, you will never need negative values in them (even more because you use AUTO_INCREMENT) and you double the capacity of your datatype.

For me the table creation statement will be:

```
CREATE TABLE relationships (
    id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    type varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY id_type (id,type)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE content_relations (
    id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    relationship_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    site_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    content_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY (relationship_id,site_id,content_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and the hints. Now that I've read this, it makes, of course, no sense to have indexes `(a)` and `(a,b)` when having already a (unique) index `(a,b,c)`. Seems like I didn't really think about this (carefully). Regarding _the PK should be simple as possible_ - why is that? I would still rather just have a `PRIMARY KEY (a,b,c)` instead of a new single-field PK and an _ordinary_ `UNIQUE KEY (a,b,c)` for the second table. Is there anything speaking against this? Thanks again.

Comment: I would too prefer to use the composite primary in such case - 2-4 numerical columns which together identify the row makes a lot of sense and the rows are often searched using those columns - sort them so if you often use only 1 or 2 of them then they are the prefix of the key - that way you best utilize the way InnoDB stores the rows (clustered by the primary key)

Answer (score 0):

After having read first @Maxime's answer, then @Rick's answer, comments and [INDEX cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql), and then having revisited, reconsidered and finally revised my queries, I ended up with the following tables and indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE relationships (
    id mediumint UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    type varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE content_relations (
    relationship_id mediumint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    site_id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    content_id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (relationship_id,site_id,content_id),
    KEY site_content (site_id,content_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

In my queries, I got rid of both `DISTINCT` and `LIMIT 1`, just because there should only be a single result (or none at all). So, after all, I have only `SIMPLE` queries that all use an appropriate index.